# Is it possible to show images in flutter app without fetching to every time firebase

Tags: firebase, flutter

I'm using flutter and firebase for my app

i want to know,

- is it possible to download images whenever user open app 1st time and when user open app 2nd time show them from memory while internet is on ?

**My Logic is----**

```
if (bool user_comes_first_time) {
    
    download images and show them;

} else {

    if (bool there_is_any_images_to_download_from_firebase) {
       
        download images;

       } else 
 
        show images without fetching from firebase ;

 }
```

Sorry for weird logic  :P

Answer (score 1):

You can use this [package](https://pub.dev/packages/cached_network_image)

```
CachedNetworkImage(
    imageUrl: "http://via.placeholder.com/350x150",
    progressIndicatorBuilder: (context, url, downloadProgress) => 
            CircularProgressIndicator(value: downloadProgress.progress),
    errorWidget: (context, url, error) => Icon(Icons.error),
 ),
```

Comment: thanks for reply, i used this package but this is not as i want